# GNOME 3 not starting on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome-shell

I install GNOME 3 on Ubuntu 16.04, however when I restart the system and try to choose an enviroment, I don't see any options. Below is a picture:
[image]

The content of /etc/X11/default-display-manager is /usr/sbin/lightdm

Any solution for this ?